# Does "one and a half of something" imply a final s for the noun?

Tags: singular-vs-plural

Is this said with or without a final s for the noun?
Should one either say: "one and a half hour" or "one and a half hours" or is either equally valid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hours is correct, with the "s". This is because there is more that 1 hour, there are 1.5 hours. Whenever there are more than 1, it is plural. Actually, anything that isn't 1 is also plural.

1.0001 hours

0.0001 hours

Comment: The answer is correct, but the reason given could be improved.  Numbers that are less than one are also pluralized: *0.1 hours*, *zero hours*.

Answer (score 1):

Any number that is not 1 is considered plural in English:

> For **1.5 hours** I've been waiting **.5 meters** from your door with **zero clothes** as the temperature has fallen to **-2 degees**.

A few comments:

- Caution is needed with certain expressions. For example, "half a mile" can be expressed as "half of a mile", so "half" doesn't actually modify the singular noun "mile".
- Zero is special because it can also modify a mass noun (e.g., "zero clothing"), which is, of course, singular.
- Some expressions use the singular regardless, e.g., "I bought a ten-gallon hat."